# Why am I getting an "uninitialized constant RefineryPage" when trying to seed after adding Refinery CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I've added RefineryCMS 2.0.3 to an existing (prelaunch, so I can smoke the db) app. I had a number of issues in upgrading to Devise 2.0 and rails 3.2 but I have gotten past them enough where the app will start. I've unfortunately hit a roadblock with Refinery though.

If I seed or if I attempt to create a page, I run into the error listed below. I've double checked and all of the migrations appear to be included (attached) and all that are are up. The database schema (partially attached) seems to be in working order.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe a gem is conflicting, but I'm not sure how. I've added my gemfile incase anyone more familiar with Rails can spot it.

Thanks!

---

**error when attempting to run rake db:seed**

```
rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant RefineryPage
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.3/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/reverse_associations.rb:34:in `block in autodetect_inverse'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.3/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/reverse_associations.rb:26:in `each'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.3/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/reverse_associations.rb:26:in `autodetect_inverse'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.3/lib/active_scaffold/extensions/reverse_associations.rb:15:in `inverse_of_with_autodetect'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:212:in `inverse_reflection_for'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:217:in `invertible_for?'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:108:in `set_inverse_instance'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:351:in `add_to_target'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:112:in `build'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `build'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:134:in `translation_for'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:77:in `fetch_attribute'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:24:in `block in fetch'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:23:in `each'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/adapter.rb:23:in `fetch'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:67:in `read_attribute'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb:114:in `block in translated_attr_accessor'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb:154:in `attribute_will_change!'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:49:in `write_attribute'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/class_methods.rb:111:in `block in translated_attr_accessor'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
(eval):3:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/globalize3-0.2.0/lib/globalize/active_record/instance_methods.rb:170:in `with_given_locale'
(eval):3:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `new'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `create!'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-pages-2.0.3/db/seeds.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:309:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/activesupport/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

---

**migrations**

```
up     20120409194703  Create refinerycms authentication schema.refinery authentication
up     20120409194704  Create refinerycms images schema.refinery images
up     20120409194705  Create refinerycms resources schema.refinery resources
up     20120409194706  Create refinerycms pages schema.refinery pages
up     20120409194707  Create seo meta.seo meta engine
```

---

**gemfile**

```
require 'rbconfig'
HOST_OS = Config::CONFIG['host_os']
source 'http://rubygems.org'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass'
end
gem 'rack'
gem 'rails', "~> 3.2"
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
gem "geocoder"
gem "geonames"
gem "devise", "~> 2.0"
gem "geocoder"
gem "geonames"
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
gem 'transloadit-rails'
gem 'uuidtools' 
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.0.beta14"
gem "squeel"
gem "pg"
gem "cancan"
gem 'kaminari'
#gem 'cantango'
gem "formtastic"
gem 'will_paginate'
gem "nested_form", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git"
gem 'tire', :git => 'https://github.com/karmi/tire'
gem 'multi_json'
gem 'active_scaffold'
gem "meta_search"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'activeadmin', :git => "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git"
gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'refinerycms-i18n',   '~> 2.0.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-blog', '~> 2.0.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-inquiries', '~> 2.0.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-search', '~> 2.0.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-page-images', '~> 2.0.0'
if HOST_OS =~ /linux/i
  gem 'therubyracer', '>= 0.8.2'
end
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.2"

group :development do
  gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.4"
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.1"
  gem "guard", ">= 0.6.2"
  gem "rails-footnotes", ">= 3.7"
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl'
  gem "guard-bundler", ">= 0.1.3"
  gem "guard-rails", ">= 0.0.3"
  gem "guard-livereload", ">= 0.3.0"
  gem "guard-rspec", ">= 0.4.3"
  gem "guard-cucumber", ">= 0.6.1"
end

group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.2.0"
  gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.1.1"
  gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.1"
  gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.6.7"
  gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5"
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.1"
  gem "guard", ">= 0.6.2"
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl'
  gem "guard-bundler", ">= 0.1.3"
  gem "guard-rspec", ">= 0.4.3"
  gem "guard-cucumber", ">= 0.6.1"
end
```

---

**partial schema**

```
 create_table "refinery_images", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "image_mime_type"
    t.string   "image_name"
    t.integer  "image_size"
    t.integer  "image_width"
    t.integer  "image_height"
    t.string   "image_uid"
    t.string   "image_ext"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

  create_table "refinery_page_part_translations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "refinery_page_part_id"
    t.string   "locale"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
  end

  add_index "refinery_page_part_translations", ["locale"], :name => "index_refinery_page_part_translations_on_locale"
  add_index "refinery_page_part_translations", ["refinery_page_part_id"], :name => "index_f9716c4215584edbca2557e32706a5ae084a15ef"

  create_table "refinery_page_parts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "refinery_page_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
  end

  add_index "refinery_page_parts", ["id"], :name => "index_refinery_page_parts_on_id"
  add_index "refinery_page_parts", ["refinery_page_id"], :name => "index_refinery_page_parts_on_refinery_page_id"

  create_table "refinery_page_translations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "refinery_page_id"
    t.string   "locale"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "custom_slug"
    t.string   "menu_title"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
  end

  add_index "refinery_page_translations", ["locale"], :name => "index_refinery_page_translations_on_locale"
  add_index "refinery_page_translations", ["refinery_page_id"], :name => "index_d079468f88bff1c6ea81573a0d019ba8bf5c2902"

  create_table "refinery_pages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.string   "path"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.boolean  "show_in_menu",        :default => true
    t.string   "link_url"
    t.string   "menu_match"
    t.boolean  "deletable",           :default => true
    t.boolean  "draft",               :default => false
    t.boolean  "skip_to_first_child", :default => false
    t.integer  "lft"
    t.integer  "rgt"
    t.integer  "depth"
    t.string   "view_template"
    t.string   "layout_template"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  end

  add_index "refinery_pages", ["depth"], :name => "index_refinery_pages_on_depth"
  add_index "refinery_pages", ["id"], :name => "index_refinery_pages_on_id"
  add_index "refinery_pages", ["lft"], :name => "index_refinery_pages_on_lft"
  add_index "refinery_pages", ["parent_id"], :name => "index_refinery_pages_on_parent_id"
  add_index "refinery_pages", ["rgt"], :name => "index_refinery_pages_on_rgt"

  create_table "refinery_resources", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "file_mime_type"
    t.string   "file_name"
    t.integer  "file_size"
    t.string   "file_uid"
    t.string   "file_ext"
    t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
  end

  create_table "refinery_roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "title"
  end

  create_table "refinery_roles_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "refinery_roles_users", ["role_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_refinery_roles_users_on_role_id_and_user_id"
  add_index "refinery_roles_users", ["user_id", "role_id"], :name => "index_refinery_roles_users_on_user_id_and_role_id"

  create_table "refinery_user_plugins", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "position"
  end

  add_index "refinery_user_plugins", ["name"], :name => "index_refinery_user_plugins_on_name"
  add_index "refinery_user_plugins", ["user_id", "name"], :name => "index_refinery_user_plugins_on_user_id_and_name", :unique => true

  create_table "refinery_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username",               :null => false
    t.string   "email",                  :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :null => false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
  end

  add_index "refinery_users", ["id"], :name => "index_refinery_users_on_id"

  create_table "seo_meta", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "seo_meta_id"
    t.string   "seo_meta_type"
    t.string   "browser_title"
    t.string   "meta_keywords"
    t.text     "meta_description"
    t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
  end

  add_index "seo_meta", ["id"], :name => "index_seo_meta_on_id"
  add_index "seo_meta", ["seo_meta_id", "seo_meta_type"], :name => "index_seo_meta_on_seo_meta_id_and_seo_meta_type"

  create_table "user_addresses", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "address_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

---

I asked this question on the Refinery CMS Google Groups earlier if you prefer to [answer there](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/adf1c9a1955e5ddf).

Comment: Could you create a repo in GitHub that isolates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squeel is the culprit as pointed out in my answer on the issue you filed on Refinery CMS: 
https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/1679

Hope that I sufficiently answered your questions :-)

Phil

https://github.com/parndt

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link, Rich!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting, I think the problem will go away if you remove 'active_scaffold' from the Gemfile (at least, I was able to instantiate a Refinery::Page locally that way, otherwise I get the same error you do). But, I would bet the problem will pop up again. From what I can tell, the problem stems from the globalize gem, which is used by Refinery Pages for translations. The Refinery::Page model calls this class macro:

```
translates :title, :menu_title, :custom_slug, :slug, :include => :seo_meta
```

which causes the globalize gem to set up several model associations automatically. The problem is, the associations don't work with namespaced models (Refinery::Page being a namespaced model). In particular, this method from Globalize::ActiveRecord::ActMacro is used for setting the class_name on the association between :"refinery/pages" and :"refinery/pages/translations" and uses basic rails conventions for inferring the model name from the db table name:

```
  def class_name
    @class_name ||= begin
      class_name = table_name[table_name_prefix.length..-(table_name_suffix.length + 1)].downcase.camelize
      pluralize_table_names ? class_name.singularize : class_name
    end
  end
```

I've been digging around in the rails source a bit to see if I can figure out how rails knows to use a namespaced model based on the table name. Haven't seen anything yet. It might be that the globalize gem would need to support an additional option being passed in on the translates macro to allow for namespaced models, and then the refinery gem would need to pass that in. Still researching.

Interesting bug.

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I'm trying to figure out how to start a second bounty because my question/answer was a bit off. The error ended up changing a bit after I moved refinery/existing codebase into a new app and updated refinery.

Comment: Hey, no problem, I saw Philip went above and beyond for you over in the github issue. Definitely worthy of the bounty.